# How to make a common subclass to remove duplicate code

Tags: c#, asp.net, oop, design-patterns

I have two classes one is derived from CheckBoxList and the second one from DropDownList. The code inside them is exactly the same. The only difference is that I need first one at places where I need to show checkboxlist and second one to show dropdownlist. Below is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

    namespace Sample
    {
        public class MyCheckBoxList : CheckBoxList
        {
            public int A { get; set; }
            public int B { get; set; }
            protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
            {
                //dummy task
                Collection<int> ints = new Collection<int>();
                //........
                this.DataSource = ints;
                this.DataBind();
            }
        }
    }
```

The second one

```
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace Sample
{
    public class MyDropDownList : DropDownList
    {
        public int  A { get; set; }
        public int  B { get; set; }
        protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
        {
            //dummy task
            Collection<int> ints = new Collection<int>();
            //........
            this.DataSource = ints;
            this.DataBind();
        }
    }
}
```

Now as you can see the internal code is exactly the same which I want to avoid. How can I make a common class for it so as to remove code duplicacy?

Comment: +1 for striving to reduce redundancy in your code. Your question may be better suited here though: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @KileyNaro: Cool to learn about codereview, didn't know it existed. Don't think its a bad match for SO either. Good question I think. +1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a third class

```
public class Entity
{
    public int  A { get; set; }
    public int  B { get; set; }
    Collection<int> GetCollection()
    {
        //dummy task
        Collection<int> ints = new Collection<int>();
        //........
        return ints;
    }
}
```

And then use it in other classes

```
public class MyDropDownList : DropDownList
{
    public MyDropDownList() { Entity = new Entity(); }

    public Entity {get;set;}
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        this.DataSource = Entity.GetCollection();
        this.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Comment: but this leads to fetch my properties like Entity.A and Entity.B. I want to avoid that. I want the properties directly from my aspx pages.

Comment: @Rocky : Encapsulate the Entity , make it private and make a property on your class to access it.

Comment: +1 for using composition, the only thing left was making Entity internal, using Encapsulation so externally it is not needed

Answer (score 0):

you can not, because c# does not support multiple inheritance of implementation (and you are already subclassing). you could refactor some of the code into a third class and have each of your classes have an instance and delegate calls to it.

you could try something like this: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/architecture/smip.aspx, but it looks like a lot of work.

Comment: Just because I'm curious and really have no idea, would you mind elaborating on how one might use delegates to achieve what the OP is looking for?

Comment: i just meant to delegate the calls to the third object. i was not referring to c#'s delegate.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I understand what you mean!

Comment: @Kiley :  That article is nonsensical, there are common design patterns to handle this, There has been no such thing as "Simulated Multiple Inheritence". Neither the code it that article works nor the name is valid. There are tested and proven design patterns to use instead.

Comment: @Arjang Hmm, interesting... I actually didn't even look at the codeproject article! Just for the sake of being thorough, could you suggest some reading on the tested and proven design patterns that you would recommend using in place of MI for C#?

Comment: @Kiley : Composition is the way they handle the benefits that MI brings, There is no need to have MI if one can have it's benefits. "Design patterns in C#" is a good starting point. also check out http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/Patterns.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

You use composition, Make another class that is not related to these two classes, then have the common code in that one, when you need to use the code in either classes you make an instance, you can also use it thorugh an interface. No need to use inheritnece.

Update : Code Below ( Modified the code already provided by meziantou)

```
 internal interface IEntity
    {
        int A { get; set; }
        int B { get; set; }
        Collection<int> GetCollection { get; }
    }

    internal class Entity : TrialBalanceHTMLToDataTable.TrialBalance.IEntity
    {
        public int A { get; set; }
        public int B { get; set; }
        public Collection<int> GetCollection
        {
            get{
            //dummy task 
            Collection<int> ints = new Collection<int>();
            //........ 
            return ints;
            }
        }
    }


    public class MyDropDownList : DropDownList
    {
        public MyDropDownList() { _Entity = new Entity(); }

        private IEntity _Entity { get; set; }
        protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
        {
            this.DataSource = _Entity.GetCollection;
            this.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

Comment: -1 to say that an interface will solve the problem; the definitions will still be duplicated between the two classes implementing the interface. But you get +1 for suggesting that the common code be moved to another class... so you break even!

Comment: @KileyNaro : LOL :) , Interfaces don't solve problems they just allow you to uniformise them!

Comment: @KileyNaro : NO! the common class wil implement the interface the other two class will only use it to talk to the class that implements it, The idea was not to implment the interfaces in two different class

Comment: I think I'm a little confused... could you provide a small snippet of code to help clarify?

Comment: @KileyNaro : Updated it modifying the code that was already provided by meziantou.

Answer (score 0):

It would seem that what you are trying to accomplish is to have a single class, that is `MyDropDownList`, be able to inherit properties from the `DropDownList`, and to have the `MyCheckBox` class inherit properties from the `CheckBox` class, while having your two My* classes have some extra properties, which happen to be identical.

As others have suggested, the easiest way to accomplish this would be through [Multiple Inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance). In your example specifically, that would mean creating a (possibly [abstract](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173150.aspx)) class that describes the shared attributes between `MyDropDownList` and `MyCheckBox`, and then have those two classes inherit from both their respective System.Web.UI.WebControls bases as well as this "shared" class. However, as it has been said, [C# doesn't support multiple inheritance.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2004/03/07/why-doesn-t-c-support-multiple-inheritance.aspx) From Chris Brumme via that link:

> The number of places where MI is truly appropriate is actually quite small. In many cases, multiple interface inheritance can get the job done instead. In other cases, you may be able to use encapsulation and delegation.

You may have also considered using [Interfaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173156.aspx). This, as you may have discovered, would be an inappropriate choice for your solution as **an Interface only allows you to define that there are certain properties and methods in a class, but not how the properties or methods are defined.** So again, this is an inappropriate choice for removing duplicate code.

What does this mean for you? Well, if you're looking to write a `MyDropDownList` class that supports both `myCustomDDLInstance.SelectedIndex` and `myCustomDDLInstance.A` syntaxes, you will have to do a little bit of "magic". **But the fact that your language doesn't support what you are trying to do should raise a red flag!** It's not necessarily wrong, but it should be a strong indicator that you may want to reexamine your design.

My guess is that the duplicated part of the two classes can stand alone as it's own logical entity. This means that you can justifiably create your own class to hold these shared properties and methods. Here's what we get:

**SampleControl.cs**

```
public class SampleControl
{
    public int A { get; set; }
    public int B { get; set; }

    public Collection<int> MysteryCollection
    {
        get
        {
            Collection<int> ints = new Collection<int>();
            //........
            return ints;
        }
    }
}
```

If CSharp did in-fact support multiple inheritance, your `MyDropDownList` class could inherit from both `DropDownList` and `SampleControl` and you'd be done. But again, this isn't possible.

So how do we accomplish your goal? It's a bit convoluted, but you can [Encapsulate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28object-oriented_programming%29) your shared properties and methods in each of your custom classes. Here's an example for the `MyDropDownList` class (note that `MyCheckBoxList` would be the same, just change the class name:

```
public class MyDropDownList : DropDownList
{
    private SampleControl mySampleControl { get; set; }

    public int A
    {
        get
        {
            return mySampleControl.A;
        }

        set
        {
            mySampleControl.A = value;
        }
    }

    public int B
    {
        get
        {
            return mySampleControl.B;
        }

        set
        {
            mySampleControl.B = value;
        }
    }

    public MyDropDownList()
    {
        mySampleControl = new SampleControl();
    }

    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        //dummy task
        this.DataSource = mySampleControl.MysteryCollection;
        this.DataBind();
    }
}
```

A class designed in this way, while a bit convoluted, should accomplish the type syntax that you are looking for.

As a final note I would strongly encourage you to at *least consider re-examining your design* and seeing if there is a better way for you to approach your class hierarchy. My recommendation is that if your shared attributes can exist on their own as a logical entity, they probably should be their own class. And if so, that class is probably a rightful and logical member of your `MyDropDownList` and `MyCheckBox` classes. Which means that you **should** be using the `myDropDownListInstance.SharedAttributesClassName.A` syntax. It's both more explicit and more honest.